# Recovering lost texts from "Mobile Operator: Couldn't get message"

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, sms, functionality, mms

I often erroneously receive MMS messages from "mobile operator." It gives me the option to download the message, but downloading it has a 100% failure rate and just changes the text to say "Couldn't get message." This happened frequently on 8.1 but has become worse since upgrading to 10.

(I'm uncertain if this is a Windows phone problem or a T-Mobile problem, but I have never seen this on Android/iOS. The errors occur when I receive a message and have cellular data enabled, but not when WiFi is enabled.)

I don't want to keep losing messages this way. How can I recover the original text?

[image]